# How can I limit my flutter application's bandwidth

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bandwidth-throttling

I'm using a youtube video player in my app and I cannot adjust the quality of the video, it automatically adjusts to the internet speed. I don't want to my app to consume mobile data, so want to limit the app's bandwidth based on the video quality the user chooses.

How can I do this?